# Scrapy: Trouble scraping UPC number correctly

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having trouble extracting the UPC code on BestBuy's webpage. When I extract for the UPC code I noticed that the UPC will move rows on each product page which will cause me to extract the wrong data.

Here are examples of UPC moving rows on a product webpage.

Product 1: CCS Selector shows `.row:nth-child(8) .col-xs-6.v-fw-regular`

Product 2: CCS Selector shows `.row:nth-child(12) .col-xs-6.v-fw-regular`

Here are two websites to inspect.

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/targus-safeport-protective-case-for-apple-9-7-ipad-5th-gen--6th-gen-and-9-7-ipad-pro-pink/6257900.p?skuId=6257900

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/belkin-dual-band-ac-gigabit-router-black/4070013.p?skuId=4070013

This is my code.

```
import scrapy
from ..item import QuotestutorialItem


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bestbuy'
    start_urls = ['https://www.bestbuy.com/site/promo/newly-discounted-outlet-products']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('div.sku-title')

        for product in products:
            item = QuotestutorialItem()
            item['title'] = product.css('div.sku-title a::text').extract()

            another_page = product.css('div.sku-title a::attr(href)').get()
            if another_page:
                yield response.follow(another_page, callback=self.parse_price, meta={'item': item})
            else:
                yield item

    def parse_price(self, product):
        item = product.meta['item']
        item['price'] = product.css('.priceView-layout-large .priceView-customer-price span::text').extract()[1]
        item['upc'] = product.css('.row:nth-child(10) .col-xs-6.v-fw-regular::text').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: did you try negative values `-1` ? OR get all rows as python's list and use  `list[-1]` to get last element on list.

Comment: No I have not tried -1 yet. That's a good idea let me try it out

Comment: It worked! I totally forgot to try that out. Thank you very much